# eShopOnContainer - Docker: Visual Studio gives 404 Page not found exception exception trying to load the SPA Web App

Tags: .net, docker, microservices

I have successfully cloned, built and run the latest Dev branch for eShopOnContainers - Microsoft's reference architecture for Microservices

> **However, I am unable to launch the SPA Webapp service
> Web SPA: http://localhost:5104 --- RETURNS 404*****

**ALL of the below endpoints work Fine**

- Web MVC: http://localhost:5100  - Works and able to launch the MVC web app
- Web Status: http://localhost:5107
- Microservices
- Catalog microservice: http://localhost:5101 (Not secured)
- Ordering microservice: http://localhost:5102 (Requires login - Click on Authorize button)
- Basket microservice: http://localhost:5103 (Requires login - Click on Authorize button)
- Identity microservice: http://localhost:5105 (View "discovery document")

Any pointers as to how to debug why the SPA WebApp is not working are much appreciated.

Comment: Hi @rexxja1, have you already found a solution to this issue? I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Solution for me was the following:

```
cd <your_repo_path>\src\Web\WebSPA\
npm install
ng build
```

Now start debugging from VS2019.
Browse to http://host.docker.internal:5104/ (or http://localhost:5104/).
You should now see the SPA app.

Answer (score 0):

#### macOS

On macOS it all worked fine as described earlier by Meeting Attender:

```sh
cd WebSPA
npm install
ng build
```

#### Windows

Install missing packages first:

```sh
cd WebSPA
npm install
```

Then I had to install [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/) to be able to run [ng build](https://angular.io/cli/build) command:

```sh
npm install -g @angular/cli
ng build
```

Without installing Angular CLI I was getting "ng: command not found" error when trying to run `ng build`.

Run docker-compose project and navigate to http://host.docker.internal:5104/.

At first I saw *ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE* page: [image]

But after ~ 20 seconds later SPA page reloaded itself automatically and everything worked fine:[image]